# Can I login to Whatsapp Web without scanning the QR code?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, camera

My camera doesn't work. I already tried downloading different camera applications but none of them worked. Problem is physical not software-related. How can I login to Whatsapp Web without scanning the QR code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, you need to scann with Whatsapp, if you scann the QR code with a normal reader, how a website or similar, you only get a plain text.

Whatsapp send that text to your own server to enable you a session in your browser.

Comment: Are you sure of the last part?

Comment: Yes, they need to process to enable you the session, that plain text don't have any data what you can read or usage how a link or anything else.

Comment: It is not that I already know how the mechanism behind it works but since it is not the webpage itself that is connecting to the servers, I don't think it is necessary to send the code to the server.

Comment: Yeah the webpage connect to the servers, but they need to know "Who" they are able to connect and enable, They need to know which User o what phone number is connecting to use the service.

Comment: Are you sure? I am pretty sure webpage **doesn't** connect to the server.

Comment: Yes Im sure, the first time you process the QR code, they send/recive your request from whatsapp and they tell to the webpage then you can use the service to chat with your contacts.

This system login is called, **SQRL** and you can see more here
[link]https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm

Comment: It probably is like this: Your phone takes QR code. Turns it into plaintext. Send it to servers. Gets an auth code in return. Send this code to webpage and a connection between your webpage and phone establishes. Webpage is just a remote control not a client.

Comment: Exactly, that is how works, or how should be.
The webpage passes to be a client after you get the auth code.

Comment: No. Webpage **never** acts as client. Just a remote control.

Comment: maybe if you grab a data packet and reproduce it with data changed with a current QR code, you could contact the servers instead of the app doing it. It would be interesting to test that out, but if the packet is encrypted by the app (almost sure it is) before it leaves to the server that would be difficult.